# Google Sheets ImportXML issues

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet that I'm trying to automate as much as possible for my WoW Raid group. What I'm trying to do here is parse some data from WoW's armory to automatically pull a persons item level.

I am having issues pulling from WoW's website directly (https://worldofwarcraft.com/en-us/character/us/sargeras/Beansy), but I can pull the item level from another site (https://raider.io/characters/us/sargeras/beansy). The only difference I can spot is that one site I can pull from a [ /div/span/b clas"text-white" ] and from WoW the information is directly in [ /div/class="media-text" ]

```
WOW Formula =IMPORTXML(C32,"//*[@id='character-profile-mount']/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]/div/div[2]")
Raider IO Formula =IMPORTXML(C31,"//*[@id='content']/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/section/div/div[1]/div/span/b")

WOW Inspect Element <div class="Media-text">184 ilvl</div>
Raider IO Inspect Element <b class="text-white">184</b>
```

Above are the respective formula's and elements I've used. Raider IO's pulls properly and outputs 184 as it's information. However WoW's does not pull properly and outputs N/A [Google Sheets Output Screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfScU.png)

Does anyone have any ideas on why this might be happening?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the `https://worldofwarcraft.com/en-us/character/us/sargeras/Beansy` prepares the values using Javascript. For example, when the HTML without using Javascript is retrieved from this URL, `Media-text` cannot be found in the retrieved HTML. On the other hand, `https://raider.io/characters/us/sargeras/beansy` has the values in the HTML without using Javascript. I thought that the difference is due to this.

But in order to retrieve the value of `184` from URL of the former, when I saw the HTML without using Javascript, I noticed that the value is included in the metadata. So when the value of `184` is retrieved from the metadata, the sample formula is as follows.

#### Sample formula:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(A1,"//meta[@name='description']/@content"),"(\d+) ilvl")
```

- In this formula, the URL of `https://worldofwarcraft.com/en-us/character/us/sargeras/Beansy` is put to the cell "A1".

#### Result:

[image]

Also, as additional modification, about your `=IMPORTXML(URL,"//*[@id='content']/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/section/div/div[1]/div/span/b")`, in this case, the xpath might be able to be modified simple a little as follows.

#### Modified formula:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//span[contains(text(),'Item Level')]/b[@class='text-white']")
```

- In this formula, the URL of `https://raider.io/characters/us/sargeras/beansy` is put to the cell "A1".

#### Result:

[image]

#### References:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)
- [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)